# Proving that the solution of a norm constrained optimization is on the boundary of the set

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization

I am trying to solve the following maximization problem

$$\max_{||x|| \leq c} x^H A x,$$ where matrix $A$ is hermitian symmetric.

I have been told that the argument of the maximum is on the ellipsoid {$||x|| = c$}, but am finding it difficult to prove it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The "ellipsoid" here is actually a ball for whatever norm is used, so a sphere if the usual Hilbert norm is intended.  In any case take the value of the bilinear form at an interior point and compare to the value at the corresponding point radially projected on the boundary of the ball.

Comment: Your use of "H" rather than "T" suggests a setting of complex vectors $x$.  If so then it raises the issue of whether the values of $x^H A x$ are real, as the application of "max" operator seems to suggest.  If $A$ is a real matrix, that would justify it, but as stated there are no "constraints on the matrix $A$".

Comment: The current edit isn't quite enough. $A$ should be Hermitian, not just symmetric, in order to ensure that the objective is real. (I see you say Hermitian in the comment below.)

Comment: @MichaelGrant Thank you for pointing that out. And it's an honor to meet you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following discussion will assume the quadratic form $x^H A x$ has only real values (so that the "max" operator can be directly applied to these values), although it is not necessarily positive definite.

The maximum will be attained on the boundary $||x|| = c$ (assuming $c \ge 0$) provided $A$ is not negative definite.  That is, if $x^H A x \ge 0$ for some $x$ with norm less than $c$, then:

$$ \frac{c x^H}{||x||} A \frac{c x}{||x||} \ge x^H A x $$

since $c^2 \gt ||x||^2$.

However if $x^H A x \lt 0$ for all nonzero $x$ (negative definite), then the maximum occurs only at $x = 0$.  For a discussion of negative definite (resp. positive definite) implying Hermitian (self-adjoint) in the complex vector space setting, see the [Wikipedia discussion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Extension_for_non_symmetric_matrices).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I rechecked the problem and found that $A$ is a hermitian symmetric matrix. I had reached the same answer on my own but I wasn't sure that my proof was rigorous enough. Thank you!