# Positive Definite Matrix A=YY'

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Show $A$ is positive definite, and find a matrix $Y$ such that $A=YY'$.

$$A =
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 & 1\\
-1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$$

I am able to show that $$xAx^T = (x_1 - x_2)^2 + \left( x_1 + x_3 \right)^2 + x_3^2$$ which is a sum of squares, therefore non-negative; and zero if $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = 0.$ Thus $A>0$. But I am unable to find $Y$ such that $$A =YY'$$
I need help on how to compute $Y$ explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. You got
\begin{align}
\langle Ax,x\rangle &= (x_1 - x_2)^2 + \left( x_1 + x_3 \right)^2 + x_3^2 \\
&= \langle (x_1-x_2,x_1+x_3,x_3),(x_1-x_2,x_1+x_3,x_3)\rangle \\
&= \langle Yx,Yx\rangle \\
&= \langle Y^TYx,x\rangle
\end{align}
where $Y$ is the matrix which acts as $T(x_1,x_2,x_3) := (x_1-x_2,x_1+x_3,x_3)$, i.e.
$$Y = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}.$$
Direct computation indeed gives $Y^TY = A$.

Comment: Your approach seems to work better. The other approaches results in cumbersome computations. Could you refer me to any theorem that deals with your approach?

Comment: Since matrix multiplication is not commutative, how do we handle $Y^TY = YY^T = A$? The question says $A=YY^T$ and you had it the other way round.

Comment: @holala My approach is just a heuristic which gives a good candidate for $Y$. In general $\langle Ax,x\rangle = \langle Y^TYx,x\rangle , \forall x \in \Bbb{R}^n$ does not imply $A=Y^TY$ so it needs to be checked. However, if we are working over $\Bbb{C}$, then from $\langle Ax,x\rangle = \langle Y^*Yx,x\rangle , \forall x \in \Bbb{C}^n$ indeed does follow $A=Y^*Y$, as per [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1010676/144766). Regarding your other comment, we have $A=Y^TY$ so if we take $Z=Y^T$ we get $A=ZZ^T$ which is your desired form.

Answer (score 0):

You should first diagonalize $ A$ i.e. write $A$ as $QDQ^T$ where $Q$ is orthogonal and $D$ is a diagonal matrix consisting of the positive eigenvalues of $A$. Then put $Y=Q\sqrt{D}Q^T$ where $\sqrt{D}$ is the diagonal matrix formed by square rooting the diagonal entries of $D$.